# Return items in order specified in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to return a page of items within an array, in the same order as the array. For example, there are 10 items. The user has saved 4 items, in the order specified (4, 1, 7, 2)

```
body: {
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          ids: {
            values: ['4', '1', '7', '2']
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Searching the following will return the 4 items, but it's a random order. Any way to tell ES to keep the order as the array?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs into this issue:

So I was trying to write a dynamic script to sort the items in ES [(see here)](https://gist.github.com/fosstrack/b16ccb726fe88c8347f9/d66bb349ae1cb97641aeea91dca9992d0cc35105) but had no luck. I ended up realizing that the hosted ES I was using only offers dynamic scripts on dedicated clusters because of security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

This looks unnecessarily complex. I'd use the following instead:

```
GET /your-index/your-type/_mget
{
   "ids" : [ "4", "1", "7", "2" ]
}
```

Quoting the [Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_retrieving_multiple_documents.html):

> The response body also contains a docs array that contains a response per document, in the same order as specified in the request.